# Flutter Custom Package (unable to load asset)

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pubspec

I've moved one of my widgets into its own custom package and everything works fine except that the image assets can't be displayed despite registering it in the `pub spec.yaml` file inside the custom component. Here is a simple example that shows the issue:

Folder structure (files are numbered):

```
.
├── lib
│   └── main.dart (1)
├── packages
│   └── showimage
│       ├── assets
│       │   └── images
│       │       └── photo.jpg
│       ├── lib
│       │   └── showimage.dart (3)
│       └── pubspec.yaml (4)
└── pubspec.yaml (2)
```

```dart
/* main.dart */

// (1)

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:showimage/showimage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: ShowImage(),
  ));
}
```

```yaml
# pubspec.yaml
# (2)

name: custom_widget
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  showimage:
    path: ./packages/showimage

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

```dart
/* showimage.dart */
// (3)

library showimage;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 0),
        child:  Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/photo.jpg')
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

```yaml
# pubspec.yaml
# (4)
name: showimage
description: Displays a photo on the screen.
version: 1.0.0
publish_to: 'none'

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.6 <3.0.0'

dependencies: {flutter: {sdk: flutter}}

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - ./assets/images/
```

When the app is run I get the following displayed in the terminal:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/photo.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:658:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/photo.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#a1e5a(), name: "assets/images/photo.jpg",
  scale: 1.0)
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

And the following displayed in the app (inside a red box crossed out):

**Unable to load asset: assets/images/photo.jpg**

The problem seems to be the image path but I've tried every variation I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a package you can use only assetImage i believe.

```dart
return const AssetImage('packages/fancy_backgrounds/backgrounds/background1.png');
```

Or

```
Image(image: AssetImage('packages/fancy_backgrounds/backgrounds/background1.png'));
```

Check this link
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: `child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/photo.jpg', package: 'showimage'))`